# How to offset labels on a web application from two different services

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, labeling, web-service, geocortex

I have multiple layers that are labeled within our online web mapping application. Two (zoning and land use) are located in our Planning/Zoning ArcGIS Server 10.1 Service. The other (Parcels) is within our 10.1 Parcels service.

Problem I'm having is that the layers are stacked on top of each other (centroid of parcel). How might I go about adjusting the label properties so that they don't appear stacked when these layers are turned on?

**Screenshot** 
the top label is from our parcels service, below that in the white mask is the future land use label from our planning/zoning service.
[image]

Comment: if you use the maplex labeling engine, I place priority on both. If you still have overlaps you can set the block on one direction for one and the other direction for the other. I'll pop some screen shots.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot showing the current overlap to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using maplex is the only fix for this I have found.
since these are polygons (points work much easier) the workaround I have found is to...

1. there are several maplex settings that will help like eroded center always within polygon.
   [image: eroded center]
   Which is in the anchor setting.
   [image: anchor]
2. interior feature weight.
   [image: feature weight]
3. then choosing place at fixed postion and setting the internal zone (top for one service and bottom for the other).
   [image: internalzones]

Comment: this assumes you have and use maplex.

Answer (score 0):

More of a Hack, but I would simply add a cartridge return after the field for parcel service, and a cartridge return before the the field future land use, in there respective label expression.  Here an example in Python

For Parcel Service

```
 [parcel_num] + '\n'
```

For Future Land Use

```
'\n' + [future_land_use_num]
```

This should offset them one on top of the other.  The downside is that the offset will remain when only one layer is turned on.

Comment: nice suggestion, but it didn't offset the labels.